# Does MLflow support distributed XGBoost model?

Tags: xgboost, mlflow

I  use single-instance xgboost model to train, which works fine with mlflow to log all the model-related parameters by using `mlflow.xgboost.autolog()`, but when i change to distributed xgboost version changing from python package to JVM package by including the xgboost4j.jar and xgboost4j-spark.jar files, and also include mlflow module into it, (`mlflow.xgboost.autolog()`). The mlflow cannot show all the parameters on the page. They are empty.
[image: screenshot]

So I looked at the source code in the mlflow.xgboost, in line 271, `def autolog(importance_types=["weight"]):` says it imports the xgboost package, which i think is the single-instance xgboost model, I wonder if it is support the distributed version? Or is there any other methods to solve the problem?